# "Uncompilable source code - Erroneous sym type" RuntimeException using Apache POI

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

```
package readexcel;

import java.io.File;
import jxl.Cell;
import jxl.Sheet;
import jxl.Workbook;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFCell;

public class ReadExcel {

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception 
{ 
    File f=new File("C:\\Users\\user1\\Desktop\\203132017.xls");
    Workbook wb=Workbook.getWorkbook(f);

    Sheet s=wb.getSheet(0);
    int row=s.getRows();
    int col=s.getColumns();
    HSSFCell cell;

    for (int j=0;j<200;j++){    
      Cell c=s.getCell(10,j);
      c.getContents();       
      c.setCellType(HSSFCell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC);       
    }
}
}
```

I'm getting the following error:

```
run:
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Uncompilable source code - Erroneous sym type: jxl.Cell.setCellType
    at readexcel.ReadExcel.main(ReadExcel.java:32)
```

Comment: Are your dependencies being included on the classpath?  Does this code look broken (as possibly flagged by your IDE)?

Answer (score 2):

You haven't mentioned the version of your `Apache POI` library. But from the error that you have described it sounds like it is > 3.15.

Please note that the method `setCellType(int cellType)` in the Apache POI class `org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFCell` is deprecated and removed. Read the [docs](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/hssf/usermodel/HSSFCell.html#setCellType(int)).

You need to use the method `setCellType(CellType cellType)` instead.

**Replace**

`c.setCellType(HSSFCell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC);`

**with**

`c.setCellType(org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.CellType.NUMERIC);`

Comment: I tried this it still didnt work. If there is another way to  convert Cell type to int    that would be great . the cell type is still underlined .

Comment: Or a way I can use if statement on Cell type

Comment: What is the new error that you get when you try my above suggestion?

Comment: what did you mean by I have to use the methode setCellType(CellType cellType) instead ?

Comment: I meant that `setCellType(CellType cellType)` was the replacement method for `setCellType(int cellType)` which was deprecated in newer versions of POI. Did you read the docs at the link I have shared in my answer? Again, what's the new error that you are getting when you try my suggestion? It's simple, will work for sure.

Answer (score 0):

Looks you are using Apache Poi. Please include all the dependencies and jars in your class path

Comment: they are in my class path, the code is working without c.setCellType(HSSFCell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC);                                       but i need it to work with this because  I want to write an if statement for the cell. when I come to write if(c=8) it says c is of type cell and 8 is int .

Comment: As per  https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/Cell.html  CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC looks deprecated. Try the following c.setCellType(HSSFCell.CellType.NUMERIC);

Comment: I changed it but it didnt work and the cellType is underlined and it says cant find symbol and still getting error when running it

Comment: I guess CellType is in different package Rather try  c.setCellType(CellType.NUMERIC) and import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.CellType;

Comment: I tried this way it fixed the celltype but the error went to the NUMERIC .